# Декремент значения в PlayerPrefs в одной строке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сократить этот код до одной строки?

```
        health = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Health");
        health--;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Health", health);
```

Comment: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Health", --PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Health"));`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Не выходит так, к сожалению((( Выдаёт ошибку: CS1059.

Comment: Я не знаю такой ошибки. У ошибки есть чёткое описание

Comment: `PlayerPrefs.Save()` забыл. О Боже как много букв!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, почему сразу посыпалось столько минусов. Формально, вопрос соответствует правилам сообщества.

---

Вариант, предложенный Алексеем Шиманским выдает у вас ошибку [CS1059](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1059): `Операндом оператора инкремента или декремента должна быть переменная, свойство или индексатор`, потому что PlayerPrefs.GetInt(...) это не переменная, не свойство и не индексатор.

Вашу проблему должно решать это:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Health", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Health") - 1);
```

Что на человеческий переводится как:

```
СохранитьЧисло("Health", ПолучитьЧисло("Health") - 1)
```

Аналогично инкремент:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Health", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Health") + 1); // Просто меняем на +
```

И тому подобное.